# "taskkill" command not working anymore

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, command-line

After installing an app, my %PATH% got reset to an empty string. I then re-added `C:\WINDOWS\system32` to it. When I run `taskkill`, I get

`"This application has failed to start because framedyn.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."`

I did a search and `taskkill` is also present in `C:\WINDOWS\$NtServicePackUninstall$`, together with `framedyn.dll`

Is it a good idea to add that directory to the path as well? Can anyone explain, what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: had same prob, this q n the a helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your PATH:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem
```

If there is no framedyn.dll file in the above folder, run `%systemroot%\system32\dllcache` from the run box and copy the framedyn.dll file from that folder to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem`.

Comment: You're very welcome!